# How can I correctly set vscode as the difftool for perforce (p4)

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, perforce, difftool

Currently I have the following:
[image]
My issue though is that when I try to do a compare, Visual Studio Code just opens both revisions in two separate tabs, not in a diff view. Is there a way I can set this up so that when the revisions are opened they're automatically opened in vscode's file comparison view?

Answer (score 2):

According to the VSCode documentation:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line

you want your argument list to be `-d %1 %2`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. I'm on a Mac if that matters. Is there a way to enable debug output to see the command p4 is calling when I try to diff?

Comment: Are you using the Mac command-line launcher described here? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac#_launching-from-the-command-line

Comment: No, I'm launching it the same as the screenshot above, just with the added `-d`. I have vscode in my path  (when I open a terminal I can type `code` to launch it fine), but nothing happens when I try to diff from perforce.

Comment: The way you're launching it probably doesn't support the `-d` command line flag. Make sure your custom tool is invoking the `code` executable rather than the app bundle or whatever the Mac thing is.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's kind of late to answer this thread but I use `/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code` as the location and it works.